# displaying controls dynamically

Tags: asp.net

I have a forgot password link. I wanna display three textboxes (old p/w, new p/w, confirm p/w) on click of the link. However these textboxes should be displayed on the same page. Is there an Ajax control for this?

Comment: You should have shown what you tried. However, you can put your controls in a div, set the div display to "none". On click of the link, use javascript to show the div

Comment: what r u using? table or div?? for the layout of the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Pannel. Make them hidden default.
Put your texbox in it.
Show it on link button.
Here is a link
http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2009/04/how-to-show-hide-visible-panel.html

Comment: If I take a panel & make it hidden, it will totally disturb the layout of the page.

Comment: not there are two things css `display` and `visibility` you can use either of them. Both have dirrerent fuctionality. Either one will be helpful for you